# singleton pattern assigning values in C#

Tags: c#, singleton

I am trying to change my code and implement singleton design patter

I have a class called Room

```
protected Room()
{

}

public static Room Instance()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        _instance = new Room();
    }
    return _instance;
}

public char room { get; set; }
```

Now I want to assign some values from main class

```
Room myRm = Room.Instance(); 

List<Room> myRoom = new List<Room>();
char[] RoomArray = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };               
foreach (char c in RoomArray)
{
    var theroom = myRm.room = c;
    myRoom.Add(theroom); <-----------does not allow me to add some
}
```

I am getting these two errors

> The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<ASR2.Room>.Add(ASR2.Room)` has some
>   invalid arguments
>
> C:\Project\c-sharp\Assignment1\Asr3\Asr3\Asr.cs
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to
>   'ASR2.Room'   C:\Project\c-sharp\Assignment1\Asr3\Asr3\Asr.cs

can some one please help?

Comment: Why are you trying  to make a list of singletons?  A more broad question is why are you using a singleton?  What is your overall goal here?

Comment: `myRoom` is defined as a `List<Room>`, but you're trying to add a `char` to the list, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: @kayze I believe you are confusing Singletons with Factory classes. A *Singleton* means that a the class is either static, or will only be instantiated once, and only once, throughout the life of the application. A *Factory* class is one that will provide a single function, for example, `Room.GetNewRoom()` and always return a new instance of a `Room` object.

Comment: @Jesse - that's a good point.  I'd suggest posting an example of that if you have time; OP might benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to the other answers attempting to help with the immediate compilation issue, this answer will explain the *other* issue.

I believe you are confusing Singletons with Factory methods. A *Singleton* means that a the class is either static, or will only be instantiated once, and only once, throughout the life of the application. A *Factory* method is a function, for example, `Room.GetNewRoom()`, which will always return a new instance of a `Room` object.

Currently, you are calling `Room.Instance()`, which will **always** return the same instance of a `Room` object (*aka, a Singleton*) created on the first call. However, inside the loop, you are assigning that single object's `room` property **a different value on each iteration!**

What this means is that at the end of the loop, the single existing instance of `Room` will simply contain the last value in the loop.

---

Now, on to fixing the issue. I think what you are looking for is a *Factory* method of sorts. From your code, I gather that you want to call a `static` function that will return a brand new `Room` object.

And *that* should look like this:

```
public static Room NewRoom()
{
    var result = new Room();
    // do things with result
    return _result;
}
```

---

Finally, your loop should look like this:

```
foreach (char c in RoomArray)
{
    var theroom = Room.NewRoom();
    theroom.room = c;
    myRoom.Add(theroom);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a `char` to a list of `Room` objects, because of this line:

```
var theroom = myRm.room = c;
```

`c` is a `char`.

Not sure, what your intention is here, but if you want a list of rooms, then change your code to this:

```
myRoom.Add(myRm);
```

But this will give you a list of the same instance of `Room`, which is not too useful.

I think you need to rethink your architecture and explain why you think you need a singleton. A list of singletons is useless.

Comment: +1 "A list of singletons is useless" - not to mention a contradiction in terms :)

Answer (score 0):

From this line:

```
var theroom = myRm.room = c;
```

So, `theroom` will be of type Char.

The following line is:

```
myRoom.Add(theroom);
```

Since `myRoom` is of type `List<Room>`, you can't add `theroom` as `theroom` is a Char, not a `Room`. And since there is no way to implicitly convert a `Char` to a `Room`, you will receive the error:

```
cannot convert from 'char' to 'ASR2.Room'
```

Comment: can I convert it from 'char' to type asr2.room?

Comment: In theory you could set that up, yes, but I don't believe there is any value to it.